# How to submit data while PHP link with HTML file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am having problem when I run the php code through html when I submit the form it show the page of file not found or deleted and when I run I separately on localhost it will successfully submits the data into database

```
<div class="top-nav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
                <h1><a class="navbar-brand wow bounceIn animated" data-wow-delay=".5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-delay: .5s;" href="index.html">PROJECT</a></h1>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom "><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom"><a href="Currency Converter.html">Currency Converter</a></li>
                    <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom active"><a href="Vehicles.html">Vehicles</a></li>
                    <li class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom"><a href="php.php">Car Registeration</a></li>
                </ul>   
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </nav>      
</div>
```

SQL code with html form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
<link href="css/form.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">  
<form id="contact" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<h3>Vehicle Registration Form</h3>
<fieldset>
  <input name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Your First Name here" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name here" type="text" tabindex="2" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input name="salary" placeholder="Enter Your Salary here" type="text" tabindex="3" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input  name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile No. here" type="text" tabindex="4" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input  name="carbrand" placeholder="Enter Your Car Brand here" type="text" tabindex="5" required>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
 </form>
 </div>
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

    $firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
    $salary=$_POST["salary"];
    $mobile=$_POST["mobile"];
    $carbrand=$_POST["carbrand"];
    $db="yasir";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $server="localhost";

    $conn=mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$db) or die();
    if($conn){
        $query="INSERT into project  VALUES(null,'".$firstname."','".$lastname."',".$salary.",".$mobile.",'".$carbrand."', null, null)";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        echo 'connected';
    }
}
?>
```

And I want the page to be redirected to home after onclick submit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have `$server="localhost"` which is part of your problem. This is looking for your dev machine. Secondly you can add the header to redirect to whichever page you like such as: `header("path/to/your/page");`

Replace localhost with your db host or IP. You can get this from your provider where you are hosting your site and d/b. Then put the header("/"); to direct users to your root(homepage). Add this piece of code after your D/B update.

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: what should i add and remove to accomplish this plzzz tell me

Comment: no dear actually i am running my whole project locally its not live i run this locally my frontend and backend work folder is save htdocs

Comment: i created a database on xampp

Comment: You can't have php in a pure HTML file. It needs to have a php extension and run on a web server with php installed. Also, if you are going to use ```header()``` you will need to put your php at the top and the correct code for the redirect would be ```header('Location: http://www.example.com/path/to/your/page');```